# Parsing a addition/subtraction/multiplication/division sign from a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I went through a lesson of creating a simple calculator using Python, and I'm trying to simplify it. 
The issue is as follows:
I know that it is possible to parse a string (number) into a float using "float()", but I'm trying to parse a addition/subtraction/multiplication/division sign from a string into a float or integer or any other format that would perform the action. Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("""
        quit - exit program
        add - addition
        sub - subtraction
        mul - multiplication
        div - division
        Please choose function:""")
    actions = ("+-*/")
    user_input_1 = float(input("first number:"))
    user_input_2 = float(input("second number:"))
    operation = user_input_1 float(action) user_input_2
    if user_input == "add":
        action = actions[0]
        answer = operation
        print (answer)
```

If the user_input is "add"
user_input_1 is "5"
user_input_2 is "7" 
then the print(answer) should result in 12

This is just the first part of the code, and I'm getting a syntax error. The issue is most likely the inability to parse the addition sign using "float()". Is there another way of parsing the signs?

Comment: Can you show some expected input and output examples?

Comment: *I'm trying to parse a addition/subtraction/multiplication/division sign from a string into a float or integer* isn't very clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 3):

Even though you should be posting the full traceback, the `SyntaxError` comes from this line:

`operation = user_input_1 float(action) user_input_2`

It is neither a valid Python expression nor a statement.

A solution that doesn't involve `eval`:
You can use the `operator` module and a dictionary from "sign" to the operator itself, as seen in this very basic (and error prone) example:

```
import operator

operations_dict = {'+': operator.add,
                   '-': operator.sub} # extend to other operators you see fit

a = float(input('first num'))
b = float(input('second_num'))
sign = input('operator')
print(operations_dict[sign](a, b))
>> first num
   1
>> second num
   2
>> operator
   +
>> 3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` in the form eval('1 + 2'), which will give you desired result.
You can read more on eval here https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval

but please keep in mind the following statement

> The user can expose hidden values in the program, or call a dangerous
>   function (dangerous_function("/etc/passwd")). Of course in most cases
>   (desktop programs) the user can't do any more than they could do by
>   writing their own python script, but in some applications (web apps,
>   kiosk computers), this could be a risk.

which is from http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html

Comment: `eval` is generally considered as something you want to avoid as much as you possibly can (especially when relying on input from users), and in this case you definitely can.

Comment: programmer can put a check for accepting only floating point numbers while taking input

Comment: Religious dogma that everyone must follow: "Never mention `eval` without also mentioning **evil** in the same sentence!" Amen. So say we all! It is known.

Comment: I added the evil part too.

Comment: This answer also doesn't really solve the `SyntaxError` OP is experiencing.,.

Comment: well this is answer for the first part, that does not support the down voting of answer as there are two part of the question.

Comment: I feel your pain, apparently there are some people who dislike simply suggestion that `eval` exists.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks, but I don't see any harm in controlled usage of eval as it is much shorter code and perform less checks than other suggested answers

Answer (score 1):

In your case this should work :

```
def operation(action): 
    return user_input_1 + action + user_input_2

if user_input == "add":
    action = actions[0]
    answer = operation(action)
    print (eval(answer))
```

but that's not the best way to do the operations. You can simply `add` or `divide` like this or you can construct a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for the operations:

```
def operation(action): 
    if(action == "add"):
        return user_input_1 + user_input_2
    elif action == "sub":
        return user_input_1 - user_input_2
    elif action == "div":
        return user_input_1 / user_input_2
    # and so on....

answer = operation(user_input)
print (answer)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. 
Why do people tell me not to use eval though?

Comment: here's a really nice answer to your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice

Comment: you can mark the answer as correct so that others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using **eval()** however; setting some rules won't hurt using eval(). This is really basic calculator and its easy to understand.

```
allowed_characters = "0123456789+-/*= "
print("""
Basic calculator application.
Operators:
    +   addition
    -   subtraction
    *   multiplication
    /   division
Type the desired operation and press ENTER. 
(Example 23 and 46 to multiple
Type 23 * 46 then press ENTER.)
""")
while True:
    data = input("Please enter your calculation: ")
    if data == "q":
        print("Exiting...")
        break
    for s in data:
        if s not in allowed_characters:
            print("Invalid character!")
            quit()
    calculate = eval(data)
    print(calculate)
```